# Isn't F# supported in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and Azure SDK 2.4

Tags: azure, f#

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and Azure SDK 2.4. I also installed "Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 -v2.4". I also tried repairing and reinstalling both the sdk and the Azure tools.

I can see 4 templates under Cloud (Azure Cloud Service,ASP.NET web application,Microsoft Azure WebJob and Azure Mobile Service) when creating a C# project.

There is no Cloud folder and no Azure templates at all when creating a F# project.

Is F# not supported or is it something wrong with my installation? I think it was supported earlier.

Comment: I don't have them too, probably they aren't present by default, need to install some additional templates.

Comment: Same problem here - they're gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F# template for Worker Roles is available as you are creating your Cloud Service project.

Create a Cloud Service project using C# or Visual Basic.

[image]

Next, as you are selecting the roles for your cloud service, you can select the F# Worker Role.

[image]

Full Disclosure: I've not actually used the F# template.  I just recall seeing it when creating my C# projects.